# Webmethods totally disabled site-wide in ASP

Tags: javascript, iis, c#, asp.net, webforms

I was screwing with the configuration for my website to fix an unrelated problem when, about a week ago, all of the webmethods on my site stopped working. Currently, whenever I make an AJAX call with any of them, the page's full HTML is returned, instead of the results of the webmethod, and the webmethod isn't executed whatsoever. I've made no changes to these webmethods and the code has worked fully before, so I know there's no issues there.

My question is, is there a configuration setting or error in IIS, web config, ASP, or anything related that I might have hit that could have disabled webmethods across the whole site? I'm really scratching my head over this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Changes to the IIS configuration `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` may prevent WebMethods from working correctly, especially changes to the `system.webServer` `handlers` node.

Check the directory `C:\inetpub\history` to find previous versions of that file and compare the current version with an older working version of `applicationHost.config` from the history.

Comment: As it turns out, I've to reinstall IIS recently (since after webmethods broke) and the history is only updated since then. Is there a way to regenerate a fresh `applicationHost.config`?

Comment: As per some other answers I found, I tried deleting it so it would be forced to regenerate but it only gave me errors and I had to restore it.

Comment: A re-install should give you a working IIS config. Any new installation of IIS should give you a clean working applicationHost.config. I don't know whether there is another way to re-create it on a single server.

Comment: Well the webmethod issue must not be with applicationHost.config then if I reinstalled IIS recently. Any other ideas? This is really killing me for development

Comment: I actually found an old Web.config that I restored and it seems like they're working again. There was a mysterious part that said the ScriptModule was disabled towards the bottom of it. Not sure how that got there, but it's working again now that it's gone. What a strange issue for the Internet not to have an answer to